# Seg Fault When Finding Length Of Last Word In A String

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a seg fault when trying to run this code, it's purpose is to find the length of the last word in a string. Any idea where this could be improved?
The scanf input is just a sentence with punctation at the end.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void clearBuffer();
void chomp(char word[]);
int lastWordLength(char word[]);

int main(){

    int x;

    char firstSen[500];
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    fgets(firstSen, sizeof(firstSen), stdin); 
    clearBuffer();
    x = lastWordLength(firstSen);
    printf("Length of last word in \"%s\" is %d.",firstSen,x);

    return 0;
}

void clearBuffer()
{
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}

void chomp(char word[])
{
    if(word[strlen(word)-1] == '\n')
    {
          word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';
    }
}

int lastWordLength(char word[])
{
    int i;
    int x;
    while(word[strlen(word)-i] != ' ')
    {
        x += 1;
        i += 1;
    }
    
    return x;
}
```

Comment: This `scanf("%s", firstSen);` doesn't input a sentence: only one word (characters up to the first whitespace). So `while(word[strlen(word)-i] != ' ')` will *never find a space*. Consider inputting with `fgets()` or with format spec `%499[^\n]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok ill change it to fgets and see what happens.

Comment: *By definition* `%s` stops scanning at the first whitespace character. That's what it does. But you'll still need to handle the case with only one word (no space is present). Some simple debugging (printing the input string) would have revealed this.

Comment: Consider using `strtok()` to parse the input string.

Comment: Please don't make rolling updates to show you code progress. If you have another question please ask it.

Comment: `x` and `i` are uninitialized in `lastWordLength` - there may be other issues as well.

Comment: @WeatherVane I went ahead and changed the scanf to fgets and edited the post, the code no longer has a seg fault but instead infinitely loops. I am mega lost so an example of a simpler case would be helpful.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane I moved some stuff around and managed to get to the output with the wrong number, but i can handle that. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

This scanf("%s", firstSen); doesn't input a sentence: only one word (characters up to the first whitespace). So while(word[strlen(word)-i] != ' ') will never find a space. Consider inputting with fgets() or with format spec %499[^\n]. –
Weather Vane

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).